# Run promises in parallel and return ordered by finish time

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have function `fetchData` that accepts an integer `id` and calls promise with random resolve time

```
  const promise = (ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('Done!');
      }, ms);
    });

    const fetchData= async (id) => {
      const ms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
      const ans = await promise(ms);
      return ans
    }
```

I have an array of `ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`  I need to call the `fetchData` with all `ids` in parallel and reorder the `ids` array based on the time taken to resolve

I tried this

```
const main = async () => {
  const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const promises = ids.map(id => fetchData(id));
  const result = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(result)
}
```

but it doesn't show which one resolved first

I added this to make it more clear
**Note:** I don't have access to edit `fetchData` function and the promises only return "Done". I can only edit the `main` function

Comment: Have you looked into using [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)?

Comment: @mykaf Yes,  Promise.all() will run them in parallel. but how to know which one resolves first? I need to reorder the array ids with the resolve order, so it may be reordered like this `ids = [5, ...]` if id = 5 finished the first one he will be the first id in the sorted list.

Comment: Perhaps the individual promises need to also somehow return the original index as well.

Comment: @Kosh I updated the question and add what I tried

Comment: @mykaf This is the issue the promises only returns `Done!`

Comment: I'm sure you could pass an index to fetchData such that you could also return that.

Comment: @mykaf In my case. I don't know what's inside `fetchData` It's a separate service that does stuff and it uses the id but it only returns "Done!" here I just mock it to make it easier to understand.
My work will only be inside the `main` function

Comment: Per the documentation, they will come back in the order passed.
"Asynchronously fulfilled, when all the promises in the given iterable fulfill. The fulfillment value is an array of fulfillment values, in the order of the promises passed, regardless of completion order. If the iterable passed is non-empty but contains no pending promises, the returned promise is still asynchronously (instead of synchronously) fulfilled."

Comment: @mykaf Yes. That why I think there is a solution other than `Promise.all` or will need to do something before call it

Comment: `finishOrder.push(id)` in your `fetchData` function before `return ans` seems like an obvious approach.  Anything wrong with that?

Comment: You can easily ___wrap___ `fetchData` if you're concerned that "it's not yours".  e.g.: `myFetchData = async (id) => { await fetchData(id); finishOrder.push(id) }`

Comment: Thanks, @Wyck  I think this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

It's done in 1 line without changing anything else:

```
const result = [];
await Promise.all(ids.map(id => fetchData(id).then(done => result.push(done))));
```

```js
  const promise = (ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(`resolved in ${ms}ms!`);
      }, ms);
    });

    const fetchData= async (id) => {
      const ms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
      const ans = await promise(ms);
      return ans
    }
    
const ids = [1,2,3,4,5];

(async() => {

  const result = [];
  await Promise.all(ids.map(id => fetchData(id).then(done => result.push(done))));
  console.log(result);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you might do it from `main` function. I assume you're interested in the processing times only, but it can be easily extended to return the actual fetched data as well.

```js
const promise = (ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('Done!');
  }, ms);
});

const fetchData = async(id) => {
  const ms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  const ans = await promise(ms);
  return ans;
}


const main = async() => {
  const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const promises = ids.map(async(id) => {
    const t0 = performance.now();
    await fetchData(id);
    return performance.now() - t0;
  });
  const result = await Promise.all(promises);
  const ids_sorted = ids.sort((a, b) => result[a - 1] - result[b - 1]);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // JSON.stringify is here for readability
  console.log(JSON.stringify(ids_sorted));
}

main()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to return 2 parameters from your function,
One will be the real answers and the second will be the time it took.

To measure the time, you can use `performance.now` native call.

When you have results of this 2 tuples you can sort them be processed time.

Answer (score -1):

I did it just for fun:

```
  const promise = (ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('Done!');
      }, ms);
  });

  const fetchData = async (id, callback = () => {}) => {
      const ms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
      const ans = await promise(ms);
      callback(id);
      return ans
  }

  const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const idsInOrder = [];
  const callback = id => idsInOrder.push(id);

  const promises = ids.map(id => fetchData(id, callback));

  Promise.all(promises)
      .then(function() {
          console.log('ids in order:');
          console.log(idsInOrder);
      })
```

I added a callback function to `fetchData` so it could record the order that the promises return in.

Comment: Don't mix callbacks with promise-returning functions